# Can Depth be used as an equivalent for MatrixQ?

Tags: matrix

Given an expression `x`, are the following two statements interchangable with no exceptions?

- `Depth[x] - 1 == 2`
- `x // MatrixQ`

If they are, which is evaluated faster?  Other than for speed, is there a reason one should be used rather than the other?

Comment: I confess to being mystified by this question. First, what is a "phrase," exactly?  Second, if we take these to be *Mathematica* expressions, it is obvious they do completely different things, leaving me wondering what you might mean by "interchangeable."  I am voting to close this as a non-question.

Comment: @whuber I think you are being exceptionally hars. While it's true that the answer is most likely not what was expected, it's still a valid question, and if someone was reading through code littered with the first check, which would work correctly some times but fail other times, it's worth asking if they are the same.

Comment: @roger For the purpose of timing expressions you should look at the doc pages for the function `Timing`

Comment: I appreciate your comment, @jVincent.  I would vote to reopen if the O.P. would at least explain *what they think each expression is supposed to be doing.*  Without that, I maintain there is no question here except as each reader individually chooses to imagine it.  Your personal construction of the question, as reflected in your answer, is reasonable, but whether it is a unique interpretation or the intended interpretation is difficult to determine.

Comment: @wuber New users to mathematica don't yet know what levels are supposed to mean, they don't know intuitively what FullForm is. Most likely he saw a function like `f[x_]/;Depth[x]-1 == 2` which should have been `f[x_?MatrixQ]`
I simply can't see the reason for closing a question because the person asking the question doesn't know enough about the system to answer it himself. His question contained everything needed though. He asked: Are they equivalent. The answer is no for reasons obvious to experienced users, but that doesn't make the question worth closing in my oppinion.

Comment: @jVincent I do not know why you are addressing that last comment to me: I have not written anything here about lack of knowledge, intuition, `FullForm`, `f[x_]`, or anything else you mention, nor have I ever suggested that the status of this question should be resolved based on our guesses about the O.P.'s state of mind. I have explained why I think this *question*, based on its merits, needs improvement, without resorting to any speculation about the knowledge or background of the person who asked it.  (And--unlike 7 other people--I have *not* downvoted it.)

Comment: @jVincent I can understand why it was closed initially — in general, questions that are simply of the form "Are A and B the same?" with absolutely no info or justification as to why A and B _might_ be the same (in some possibly incorrect view), don't make much sense, because you can substitute **anything** in A and B and you'll **always** have a yes/no answer. Depending on how diverse the two objects are, you can choose to answer with a simple yes/no (e.g. "Are chimpanzees and gorillas the same?") or simply say that the question is absurd (e.g. "Are gorillas and chickens the same?"). [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] In this case, several folks felt that comparing `Depth` and `MatrixQ` fell into the latter category and coupled with the lack of reasoning, it was NaRQ (which is what @whuber was saying above). Note that the `==2` part was added later by Istvan in what is a major change to the question and was _not_ made by the OP (there are no deleted comments by the OP either). So the original closure was fully justified. I've reopened this now, because for good or for bad, Istvan's edit + your interpretation makes a compelling case for a possible source of confusion and thus is a worthy question.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be confused about what they both do. While it's true that a matrix with only numerical entries will give `True` for the first definition, they are not the same:

```
 {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} // {Depth[#] - 1 == 2, MatrixQ[#]} &
```

> {True, True}

```
 {Sin[k], {3, 4}} // {Depth[#] - 1 == 2, MatrixQ[#]} &
```

> {True, False}

```
 {{Sin[y], 2}, {3, 4}} // {Depth[#] - 1 == 2, MatrixQ[#]} &
```

> {False, True}

I can't say for certain what you are using this for, but I'd bet that you want `MatrixQ` and not the other test.